# IntegerDigits has Listable attributes, but not fast

Tags: performance-tuning

See this example,  a function has `Listable` attributes often more efficient than `Map`,but why is this one is an exception?

```
With[{n = 6},
   IntegerDigits[Range[10^(n - 1), 10^n - 1]]
   ] // Hash // AbsoluteTiming
(*{1.573090, 756716557}*)

With[{n = 6},
   IntegerDigits /@ Range[10^(n - 1), 10^n - 1]
   ] // Hash // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.202012, 756716557}*)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Map` is autocompiling. If you turn autocompilation off, i.e., if you set

```
SetSystemOptions[
  "CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength" -> Infinity];
```

then the timings are the same.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: But you _artificially_ made `Map` slower.